# How to get file path to work for another user in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a small **python program** that uses **Tkinter** and I need to refer certain file paths in it sometimes. The program works **perfectly** but when I send the program to my friend he isn't able to run it properly. I know the problem lies in the fact that the directories do not match for my computer and my friend's computer but I want it so that the code works for all computers, not just mine.

**If you're going to tell me to save the files in a database then please tell me how to do it in detail**

My code:-

Again, its a python file

```
import winsound
from tkvideo import tkvideo
from tkinter import *


mywin = Tk()
mywin.title("Tkinter app")
mywin.geometry("1920x1080")
mywin.iconbitmap("C:/Users/my user/Desktop/MyApp/config/tk_icon.ico")


tkvid = Label(mywin,text="Never gonna give you up")
vidplay = tkvideo("C:/Users/my user/Desktop/MyApp/config/vid1.mp4",tkvid,loop = 1,size = (700, 500))

tkvid.pack()
vidplay.play()
winsound.PlaySound("C:/Users/my user/Desktop/MyApp/config/se1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_LOOP|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
mywin.mainloop()
```

Please reply to my question. Been trying to find an answer for long and finally decided to create a stackoverflow account to be able to ask a question. Hoping to get a response that helps me and thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: Use relative path instead of absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Get their user, and just fill in the path with that username. The code snippets below automatically send it to the desktop, you can change that easily if you do want. Also, just download the files from google drive using [Google Drive API (Python Wrapper)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)

Linux:

```py
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')
```

Windows:

```py
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
```

Comment: thanks. i based my program off of that and like before it works perfectly. just need to test it out with my friends and btw its a rickroll ;)